# I need a Linux GUI distro which is lightweight and supports Python 3.7+

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, small-distribution

I am in search of a Linux "GUI" distro which also has python

the distro must be under these criterion:

```
1. Be able to run on Virtual Box
2. ISO under 250mb
3. Total OS disk space: below 2.5gb
4. RAM needed: under 500mb
5. Have sudo, etc.. pre-installed
6. be able to run python 3.7 or above
7. it is a GUI OS
8. it doesn't matter if it is x86 or arm or x64
9. have basic necessary softwares:
   + terminal
   + code editor
   + nothing more
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17130/116858 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3910/116858

Comment: I like [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org/) -- lightweight, runs on VM, low requirements, many GUI options, not a lot installed by default

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this with Debian 10 (buster) using the MATE desktop environment using one of the netinst CDs.  I've taken the live CD and run it in a virtual machine, and here's how it stacks up:

1. Debian is able to run on most emulated hardware.
2. The netinst (net install ISO) is 336 MB, but you could use netboot.xyz to PXE boot a smaller installation image over the Internet.
3. The entire live CD fits into 2.9 GB and it also contains material to install the full OS, so a fully featured OS should fit well below 2.5 GB.  You can also choose to install more packages by hand to shrink the default install.
4. The live CD takes a little over 300 MB to run, plus kernel memory.
5. You can choose to install `sudo` by not setting a root password.  Debian also has probably the largest package archive of any modern distro.
6. The version of Python 3 is Python 3.7.
7. This comes with MATE.  If you want, Xfce is also a possibility.
8. Debian is one of the most portable Linux distributions and runs on all of those architectures.
9. This install comes with a terminal, and a tiny version of Vim (invocable as `vi`).  Other editors can be installed, although due to your memory constraints, your choice of editors may be limited.

The only one where it doesn't clearly satisfy your needs it the ISO size, but as I said, you can probably shrink the amount of data by booting it over the network, which will likely download less data.  You will, of course, have to install packages over the network, but as a practical matter, that is required since nobody is going to ship a full OS and GUI in under 250 MB.

Note that Debian 11 (bullseye) is scheduled to be released tomorrow, so you may wish to hold off for a day and install the new version.

Comment: not the thing that i needed.. it still needs about 600mb in downloading base system